# mobx-state-tree error while converting to anonymousModel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

**What should happen** - succesfully create RootStore from defaultSnapshot and reset it when needed, successful backcuping in localStorage.
**What happens** - getting an error while trying to apply a snapshot, when attempting to open page, just by running code even without interacting with it.

When checking types manually I do not see problems with type mistakes, so can not understand why it throws error.

[Codesandox live minimum code](https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-state-tree-error-converting-to-model-q26le?file=/src/store.js)

**Error**

```
Error: [mobx-state-tree] Error while converting `{"token":"","myInnerInfo":{"login":"","type":""},"myDisplayInfo":{"login":"","type":""},"loginInfo":{"login":"","type":""},"loginList":[],"loading":false,"logined":false}` to `AnonymousModel`:

    at path "/myInnerInfo/login" value `""` is not assignable to type: `AnonymousModel` (Value is not a plain object).
    at path "/myInnerInfo/type" value `""` is not assignable to type: `AnonymousModel` (Value is not a plain object).
    at path "/myDisplayInfo/login" value `""` is not assignable to type: `AnonymousModel` (Value is not a plain object).
    at path "/myDisplayInfo/type" value `""` is not assignable to type: `AnonymousModel` (Value is not a plain object).
    at path "/loginInfo/login" value `""` is not assignable to type: `AnonymousModel` (Value is not a plain object).
    at path "/loginInfo/type" value `""` is not assignable to type: `AnonymousModel` (Value is not a plain object).
```

**File structure**

[image]

**store.js** (imported in index.js)

```
import { types, flow, onSnapshot, applySnapshot } from 'mobx-state-tree';
import { values } from 'mobx';
import axios from 'axios';

const defaultSnapshot = {
  token: '',
  myInnerInfo: { login: '', type: '' },
  myDisplayInfo: { login: '', type: '' },
  loginInfo: { login: '', type: '' },
  loginList: [],
  loading: false,
  logined: false,
}

const User = types
  .model({
    login: '',
    type: '',
  }).actions(self => ({
    setUserInfo({ login, type }) {
      self.login = login;
      self.type = type;
    }
  }))

const RootStore = types
  .model({
    token: '',
    myInnerInfo: types.map(User),
    myDisplayInfo: types.map(User),
    loginInfo: types.map(User),
    loginList: types.array(types.string),
    loading: false,
    logined: false,
  }).views(self => ({
    get loginListLength() {
      return values(self.loginList).length;
    },
  })).actions(self => ({
    // setToken (token) {
    //   self.token = token;
    // },
    // setMyInnerInfo (userInfo) {
    //   self.myInnerInfo.setUserInfo(userInfo);
    // },
    // setMyDisplayInfo (userInfo) {
    //   self.myDisplayInfo.setUserInfo(userInfo);
    // },
    // setLoginInfo (userInfo) {
    //   self.loginInfo.setUserInfo(userInfo);
    // },
    // setLoginList (loginList) {
    //   self.loginList = loginList;
    // },
    // setLoading (loading) {
    //   self.loading = loading;
    // },
    // setLogined (logined) {
    //   self.logined = logined;
    // },
    // reset() {
    //   self.token = '';
    //   self.myInnerInfo = User.create({});
    //   self.myDisplayInfo = User.create({});
    //   self.loginInfo = User.create({});
    //   self.loginList = [];
    //   self.loading = false;
    //   self.logined = false;
    // },
    register: flow(function* register(login, password) {
      self.loading = true;
      try {
        const res = yield axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}/users/register`,
          data: { login, password },
        });
        alert('Registered');
        self.loading=false;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        alert(`Error registering! Please retry!`);
        resetStore();
      }
    }),
    login: flow(function* login(login, password) {
      self.loading = true;
      try {
        const res = yield axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}/users/login`,
          data: { login, password },
        });
        self.token = res.data.token;
        self.myInnerInfo.setUserInfo(res.data.user);
        self.myDisplayInfo.setUserInfo({ login: '', type: '' });
        self.loginInfo.setUserInfo({ login: '', type: '' });
        self.loginList = [];
        alert('Logined');
        self.logined = true;
        self.loading=false;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        alert(`Error logining! Please retry!`);
        resetStore();
      }
    }),
    unlogin() {
      self.loading = true;
      self.logined = false;
      self.token = '';
      self.myInnerInfo.setUserInfo({ login: '', type: '' });
      self.myDisplayInfo.setUserInfo({ login: '', type: '' });
      self.loginInfo.setUserInfo({ login: '', type: '' });
      self.loginList = [];
      alert('Unlogined');
      self.loading=false;
    },
    getMyInfo: flow(function* getMyInfo() {
      self.loading = true;
      try {
        const res = yield axios({
          method: 'GET',
          url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}/users/my-info`,
          headers: {'Authorization': self.token ? `Bearer ${self.token}` : ''},
        });
        // self.token = res.data.token;
        // self.myInnerInfo.setUserInfo(res.data.user);
        self.myDisplayInfo.setUserInfo(res.data);
        // self.loginInfo.setUserInfo({});
        // self.loginList = [];
        alert('Loaded information');
        // self.logined = true;
        self.loading=false;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        alert(`Error loading information! Please retry!`);
        resetStore();
      }
    }),
    getLoginList: flow(function* getLoginList() {
      self.loading = true;
      try {
        const res = yield axios({
          method: 'GET',
          url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}/users/list-logins`,
          headers: {'Authorization': self.token ? `Bearer ${self.token}` : ''},
        });
        // self.token = res.data.token;
        // self.myInnerInfo.setUserInfo(res.data.user);
        // self.myDisplayInfo.setUserInfo(res.data);
        // self.loginInfo.setUserInfo({});
        self.loginList = res;
        alert('Loaded list');
        // self.logined = true;
        self.loading=false;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        alert(`Error loading list! Please retry!`);
        resetStore();
      }
    }),
    getUserInfo: flow(function* getUserInfo(login) {
      self.loading = true;
      try {
        const res = yield axios({
          method: 'GET',
          url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}/users/my-info/${login}`,
          headers: {'Authorization': self.token ? `Bearer ${self.token}` : ''},
        });
        // self.token = res.data.token;
        // self.myInnerInfo.setUserInfo(res.data.user);
        // self.myDisplayInfo.setUserInfo(res.data);
        self.loginInfo.setUserInfo(res.data);
        // self.loginList = [];
        alert('Loaded information');
        // self.logined = true;
        self.loading=false;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        alert(`Error loading information! Please retry!`);
        resetStore();
      }
    }),
  }));

const store = RootStore.create();

if(!(localStorage[process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALSTORAGE_KEY] && JSON.parse(localStorage[process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALSTORAGE_KEY]))) {
  localStorage[process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALSTORAGE_KEY] = JSON.stringify(defaultSnapshot);
}
applySnapshot(store, JSON.parse(localStorage[process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALSTORAGE_KEY]));

onSnapshot(store, snapshot => {
  localStorage[process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALSTORAGE_KEY] = JSON.stringify(snapshot);
  console.info(snapshot);
});

export default store;
export function resetStore() {
  localStorage[process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALSTORAGE_KEY] = JSON.stringify(defaultSnapshot);
  applySnapshot(store, JSON.parse(localStorage[process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALSTORAGE_KEY]));
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "mobx": "^6.0.4",
    "mobx-react": "^7.0.5",
    "mobx-state-tree": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are `myInnerInfo`, `myDisplayInfo` and `loginInfo` intended to have multiple values? Because `types.map` defines a collection of multiple values, not singular (scalar) values...

Comment: while testing, you probably want to reset local storage each time, so that it doesn't give you results based on data from previous runs. That can make it really hard to see what's going on. One way to handle this is if there is an error loading from local storage, reset local storage so that it will be fixed next load. In production, you may want to do something like this so loading data when your model changes still works...

Comment: @GarrettMotzner yes, they should contain two strings, I know about this problem with localStorage, I reset it from browser when having such problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your `defaultSnapshot` does not match your defined model structure.
You define your default snapshot as follows:

```js
const defaultSnapshot = {
  token: '',
  myInnerInfo: { login: '', type: '' },
  myDisplayInfo: { login: '', type: '' },
  loginInfo: { login: '', type: '' },
  loginList: [],
  loading: false,
  logined: false,
}
```

However, if you `getSnapshot` of your `store` after you create it with no arguments, you get:

```js
{
 token: "",
 myInnerInfo: {},
 myDisplayInfo: {},
 loginInfo: {},
 loginList: [],
 loading: false,
 logined: false
}
```

Which would be a "default snapshot" in the sense that it is what happens when you `create` your store with no specific data.

Now this looks like the two should be compatible, except that you defined the three `Info` fields as `map`s. Maps of models look like this:

```js
{
  "<id>": { <model snapshot> },
  …
}
```

Therefore, when loading your default snapshot, it causes an error because it tries to treat what you intended to be model data as map data - it thinks you have a collections of two `Users` with keys of `login` and `type`, and values of `""`, instead of objects compatible with `User`. For instance,

```js
…
myInnerInfo: { 
  login: { login: 'some user data', type:'' }, 
  type: { login: 'another user data', type:'' }
},
…
```

Would work, but doesn't seem like what you intended.

What you probably intended to do was make the `Info` fields directly of the `User` type, not a `map` of the `User` type, or perhaps an `optional` or the `User` type, since then you don't need to specify a `User` when creating the store. So perhaps your store model should look like this:

```js
.model({
    token: '',
    myInnerInfo: types.optional(User, {}),
    myDisplayInfo: types.optional(User, {}),
    loginInfo: types.optional(User, {}),
    loginList: types.array(types.string),
    loading: false,
    logined: false,
  })
```

This structure is compatible with your default snapshot, and does not require values when creating the store.

Note that primitive values are automatically optional, but models are not (hence why the explicit `optional` call). An `optional` parameter has a default value, but will still exist. It just does not need to be explicitly defined at `create` time. Also, be sure to reset your `localStorage` when testing, or it may seem like it didn't work...

Comment: What I was trying to achieve to have a root store with a shape of my defaultSnapshot object, because if it is not initialized correctly it will throw error on self.(any nested user info).setUserInfo. Also I would not like to have undefined values after creating store and to be able to reset its state to defaultSnapshot structure with calling some function

Comment: The model above will create an object with a snapshot that matches your default snapshot on `.create()`, and will accept the `default_snapshot` when calling `apply_snapshot`. Also, notice that `optional` provides a a default value as the second argument, so it is always defined, but does not need to be provided.

Comment: I made nested objects in defaultSnapshot empty, code now https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-state-tree-error-converting-to-model-forked-np49t?file=/src/store.js, but when trying to login in real local app, I get error 'self.myInnerInfo.setUserInfo is not a function', how can it be not error?

Comment: Looks like you still are defining them as `map` collections of users. Is that what you really want? Form you usage, it seems like that is not true. You need to change your model, as mentioned above...

Comment: If you define `myInnerInfo` as a `map`, then it is not a `User` object, but a _collection_ of `User` objects. Therefore, `setUserInfo` is not defined on the collection, because it isn't a `User`. (However, if you get an item in that collection, it would be defined). If you use `optional` instead of map, you will get a `User` object, not a collection.

Comment: I would like to use simple objects for snapshots, tried to do that and still having error `[mobx-state-tree] Error while converting `{}` to `AnonymousModel`:

    at path "/myInnerInfo" value `undefined` is not assignable to type: `reference(AnonymousModel)` ........` - how can it be done? Code: https://gist.github.com/bpalij/d27e7d294d8c86b1ffc46d706259b60c

Comment: `types.compose(…)` is only necessary when you need to merge the data from multiple other types. That's not what you are doing here. If you use optional, it will work, like you want, automatically creating user objects, instead of leaving them empty. https://gist.github.com/cableray/56b7b1cccbcac66cb2076a47feffb69c